# Delete class if variable get

Tags: javascript, html, display

If there is a variable get (SID) it is necessary to delete the existing class (forceview)

Url Exemple: https://example.com/?SID=eqwe7q7e6868

I'm taking the variable and trying to insert a display (none).

```js
function sid() {
  // Gets a url that includes the `?` character
  var url = "somedomain.net?search";
  if (url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    // Selects elements with the "forceview" class
    const forceviews = document.getElementsByClassName("forceview");
    // Loops through these elements and removes them from display
    for (let forceview of forceviews){
      forceview.style.display = "none";
    }
    console.log("all `.forceview` elements have been hidden");
  }
}
sid();
```

```css
span.old-price.sly-old-price.no-display.forceview {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display forceview">
  <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
    <span class="price-label">Preço Normal
    </span>
    <span id="old-price-1263-final_price" data-price-amount="19.9" data-price-type="oldPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
      <span class="price">R$19,90</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

The code returns no errors.

Comment: document.getElementById ??

Comment: sorry,modify...

Comment: You are targetting a class by `getElementById`, change it to `querySelector`.

Comment: Note: `getElementsByClassName` requires the element index.

Comment: Well, you don't define `spans` in this code, so you should be getting an error there, except that you don't call `sid()` except within the `sid` function itself, so nothing happens when you run the code...

Comment: There should be errors in the console `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection so there is no style so reading the display of undefined is an error. You also have `const span = spans[i];` but do not use it. You also are calling the method `sid();` inside of the function so it never gets called! ANd there are other small typos.

Comment: How would it be?

Comment: Don't put a `.` before the class when you call `getElementsByClassName()`. That's only used in selectors, not this function.

Comment: Can there be more than one `forceview` element? Do you need to hide them all?

Comment: Why does `sid()` call itself at the end?

Comment: Why do you have the `for` loop? You never do anything with the `span` variable. Where do you declare the `spans` array?

Comment: I noticed that you updated the code in your question to be a near-verbatim copy of my answer to the original question. I think this is confusing at best. Generally, it's better to add an answer if you want to document a modified answer (rather than replacing the question itself. (At this point it might be difficult to "undo" this action, but just for future reference I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```js
function sid() {
  // Gets a url that includes the `?` character
  var url = "somedomain.net?search";
  if (url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    // Selects elements with the "forceview" class
    const forceviews = document.getElementsByClassName("forceview");
    // Loops through these elements and removes them from display
    for (let forceview of forceviews){
      forceview.style.display = "none";
    }
    console.log("all `.forceview` elements have been hidden");
  }
}

sid();
```

```html
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display forceview">
  <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
    <span class="price-label">Preço Normal
    </span>
    <span id="old-price-1263-final_price" data-price-amount="19.9" data-price-type="oldPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
      <span class="price">R$19,90</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Can I put important in js? display:none !important;

Comment: That's right, but I saw that my css has an important inline, which I need to overwrite.
I can?

Comment: Done using, forceview.style.cssText = 'display:none !important'; Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName() does not accept css selector.
You should write

```
document.getElementsByClassName("forceview")[0]
```

> [0] beacuse document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of
>   elements.

Comment: that is still not all the issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

I see many mistakes:

• you should run your function outside of the function (not inside).

• you try to get a class with `getElementById`, you should use `getElementsByClassName` I think.

• you are looping through `spans.length` but what is spans? you don't declare it anywhere.

Comment: `getElementById` was fixed in an edit 30 minutes ago.

Comment: Can I put important in js?

Comment: I guess yes like that:  ```style.display = "none!important";```